# The game of Chuck-a-Luck

Tags: probability

The game of Chuck-a-Luck is described as follows [here](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Fifty_Challenging_Problems_in_Probabilit/8EDCAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=50%20challenging%20problems&printsec=frontcover). A player may bet on any one of the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6. Three dice are rolled. If the player's number appears on one, two, or three of the dice, he receives respectively one, two, or three times his original stake plus his own money back; otherwise he loses his stake. What is the player's expected loss per unit stake? (Actually the player may distribute stakes on several numbers, but each such stake can be regarded as a separate bet.)

My approach is as follows:-
Since the problem is symmetric, I took a bet on one single number, say $4$. Now, the expected amount I win (including the original stake) is:

```
Occurance     Loss
   0            1 
   1            0
   2           -1
   3           -2
```

And getting a $4$ in n dies is:

```
   n          Prob
   0        125/216 
   1         75/216
   2         15/216
   3          1/216
```

which would make my expected loss

$$\frac{1\times 125 + 0\times 75 - 1 \times 15 - 2 \times 1}{216} = 0.5$$

The answer can be found in the book provided, which comes out to be ~8%. In the author's approach, he has considered expected winnings instead of the expected loss. While calculating the loss, why is he not including the original stake?

Comment: The question might be - why are *you* not including the return of the original stake in your computation of "loss"?  My interpretation of "he receives respectively one, two, or three times his original stake plus his own money back" is that the 0, 1, 2, and 3 match events correspond to "losses" of 1, -1, -2, and -3 respectively (and not 1, 0, -1, and -2, as in your chart).  For example the "1 match" event is a win state where you gain money - receiving not just your stake back, but 1x your stake on top of that.  With those numbers in your method, you would get an expected loss of about 0.0787

Comment: In fact, the game as described would be a $50$-percent loss.

Comment: @leslietownes: Your comment should have been an answer, as the only one that has explained the **error in the asker's attempt**.

Comment: @user21820 I find it good when questions just based on misunderstandings are just commented , not answered , although I also upvoted the answer in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are computing is incorrect. The book is computing the **net** win. Whether you compute net win or net loss, the figure will come the same, only sign will change. By keeping the stake out of the computation of wins, the computation of net win/loss is simpler.

$E(W) = \dfrac{-1*125 +1*75+2*15+3*1}{216}= \dfrac{-17}{216}$

Comment: So, it makes sense.

Comment: Yea, the people who set up these games always make sure that you are on the losing side (on average) ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: But not 50% :) By the way , many people think they have an edge since every dice has probability 1/6 to hit , so they assume that they have 1 hit an average and sometimes more. Of course , this is a fallacy , they miss the repeated different numbers.

Comment: Craps is a far fairer and more popular casino dice game.